# Iterate through 3 dimensional radius in world from center position

Tags: java, iteration, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to get all positions in a radius from a 3 dimensional world(In this case the game Minecraft) this is the current code I use.

```java
    public static List<BlockPos> getBlocksInRadius(double radius) {
        List<BlockPos> circleblocks = new ArrayList<>();
        int centralx = mc.player.posX;
        int centraly = mc.player.posY;
        int centralz = mc.player.posZ;
        for (int x = centralx - radius; x <= centralx + radius; x++) {
            for (int z = centralz - radius; z <= centralz + radius; z++) {
                for (int y = centraly - radius; y < centraly + radius; y++) {
                    double dist = mc.player.getDistance(x, y, z);
                    if (dist < radius) {
                        BlockPos l = new BlockPos(x, y, z);
                        circleblocks.add(l);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return circleblocks;
    }
```

This method goes from the x coord farthest away and keeps coming closer to the player. I want it to iterate it by starting at central x,y,z and then increase distance from the player. This is to make it easier to find block x closest to player. Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: Try using recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how large of a radius you have, you might try the static method `BlockPos::getAllInBox`. There doesn't seem to be any official documentation on it, but it looks like it takes two `BlockPos` parameters and returns an `Iterable<BlockPos>`. It finds all the blocks in a cube in between the two parameters, so you probably want to center it on the player.

Here's what I would do. This code hasn't been tested, and you might need to adapt it for all of the 1.14 and 1.13 changes, but the theory should be the same, with just name changes.

```
BlockPos playerPos = player.getPosition(); // Or some other method of getting a BlockPos of the player
positiveRadiusPosition = playerPos.add(radius, radius, radius); // Gets one corner of the cube in the positive X, Y, and Z direction
negativeRadiusPosition = playerPos.add(-1 * radius, -1 * radius, -1 * radius); // Gets the opposite corner

Iterable<BlockPos> cubeResult = BlockPos.getAllInBox(positiveRadiusPosition, negativeRadiusPosition);

for (BlockPos pos: cubeResult) {
  // cubeResult will contain blocks that are outside of the sphere with the 
  // radius you want. If that's okay, cool! If that's not okay, you should
  // check each pos' distance from the player. If it's outside of the radius,
  // remove it from the list.
}
```

Now you need to figure out which block is closest. The method I would use would be to use a [Comparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/) to sort the Iterable, which is copied into a List. For reference:

```
public static Iterator sortedIterator(Iterator it, Comparator comparator) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        list.add(it.next());
    }

    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    return list.iterator();
}
```

In the Comparator, you should check the distance from the player to each block.

```
public static double getDistanceToEntity(Entity entity, BlockPos pos) {
    double deltaX = entity.posX - pos.getX();
    double deltaY = entity.posY - pos.getY();
    double deltaZ = entity.posZ - pos.getZ();

    return Math.sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY) + (deltaZ * deltaZ));
}
```

Of course, this method doesn't actually start at the player and work outwards. It's just a cleaner and expanded version of your original method that should do what you want. If you are working with a very large radius, it's probably not a good idea to use this, as you'll have to work with the entire cube.